# I have to write a function that has two arguments(two lists of numbers, and returns its inner product), without using list comprehension, any ideas?

Tags: python, list, inner-product

```py
def inner_product(vec1,vec2):
    if len(vec1)==len(vec2) and len(vec1)!=0:
        return sum([vec1[n]*vec2[n] for n in range(len(vec1))])
    else:
        return 0
```

Is the code that I built contain using list comprehension? if yes what can I do instead of this?

Comment: Yes, it's List Comp in the current *form*.  You can change to - 1) for-loop; or 2) generator expression by removing the ```[``` and ```]``` square bracket.

Comment: Yes `[vec1[n]*vec2[n] for n in range(len(vec1))]` is a list comprehension. Just convert it in an explicit `for` loop

Comment: It's weird task though, maybe you need to use functional approach instead: `sum(map(mul, vec1, vec2))`. Imports: [`mul()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Without list comprehension, it would be something like below.

```py
def inner_product(vec1,vec2):
    if len(vec1)==len(vec2) and len(vec1)!=0:
        temp=[]
        for n in range(len(vec1)):
            temp.append(vec1[n]*vec2[n])
        return sum(temp)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: How about `temp = 0` and `temp += vec1[n] * vec2[n]`?

Answer (score 0):

A basic *for*-loop approach.

```
def inner_product(vec1, vec2):
    result = 0
    if len(vec1) == len(vec2) and len(vec1) != 0:
        for i in range(len(vec1)):
            result += vec1[i] * vec2[i]
    return result


print(inner_product([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
#32
print(inner_product([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 5555]))
#0
```

Notice that your current implementation returns `0` if the vectors have different length... but careful that a inner product return zero if and only if the two vectors are *orthogonal* to each other (assumed both vectors non zero)... and this geometrical result will fail. Raising an exception would be a good choice to fix it: `raise Exception("Error, vectors non comparable")`